# Emojis not rendering on an Android phone in React

Tags: html, reactjs, emoji

On a computer and tablet (iPad mini, for instance), it is working fine, but on Andriod phone (Samsung Note 3), it is not rendering at all. Just a bunch of boxes with crosses.

Here's what it looks like on Chrome Devtools:

[image]

What really happens on a real phone:

[image]

I have tried using both the decimal (dec) or hexadecimal (hex), but unfortunately, none of them helped at all.

Here's a code sample where I'm trying to render a nerd face:

```html
<li className="sidebar-list">
                            <span role="img" aria-label="list" className="list-icons">
                                
                            </span>
                            Privacy policy
                        </li>
```

Here are more code examples on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-menu-li9so).

**Edit: Added images for better illustration of the problem**

Comment: Perhaps the device you're using and the OS installed doesn't support those emojis you picked? Looks like `Note 3` was released in 2013 so there's a good chance it's running an older OS that doesn't support those emojis.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I am trying to replicate a social platform that has emojis on their homepage. If their emojis is working fine on my phone, then it should also work on my web app. There's a chance that they are using SVG, so I'll keep that as an option.

Comment: `dev.to`? They are using `SVG`s and that is definitely the case - whatever OS you're testing doesn't support those emojis.